# Error importing a package under pytest

Tags: python, pytest

In my piece of python code, I am using dynamic importing with:

```
def load_class(path, class_str):
    """
    :param path: Function to load class dynamically
    :param class_str:
    :return:
    """
    module = importlib.import_module(path)
    return getattr(module, class_str)
```

I am calling this func as

```
class_name = "CL_ABC"
path = "test.test_framework.test_a_feature"
testclass = load_class(path, class_name)
```

I am getting error as

```
ImportError: No module named test_framework.test_a_feature
```

I am calling above code from a file having unittest framwork. Suppose file name is `test1`, if I am calling as `python test1` it is working fine but if I am calling this as `pytest test1`, I am getting above error.

Comment: Your function works for the standard library: `load_class('unittest.case', 'TestCase')`. Are you *absolutely sure* that `test.test_framework.test_a_feature` exists? What does `sys.modules['test'].__file__` produce, is it the correct package?

Comment: This is almost certainly a failure with a different `test` module being found first, before your own `test` package. So this is a `pytest` specific issue, not a problem with `importlib`.

Comment: load_class works if I am calling as `python test1`. I am using unittest currently. I thought of using pytest so I called the python code as `pytest test1`. I started getting the error. That means test.test_framework.test_a_feature exists

Comment: How should I debug . I am struggling since last 5 hours

Comment: I'm saying that this is a `pytest` issue, not a `importlib` issue. You probably will get the exact same traceback if you used `from test.test_framework.test_a_feature import CL_ABC`. Simplify the problem down!

Comment: Next, use `import test` and print `test.__file__` to see what is being imported. It is the `test_framework.test_a_feature` nested modules that are failing here, not the top-most `test` package or module.

Comment: Note: you really should not name your package 'test', as there is already a [Python standard library module of the same name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html). I strongly suspect that that your error is a symptom of your `sys.path` not being correctly configured to find your package, so the standard-library module is found instead.

Comment: Also see [PATH issue with pytest 'ImportError: No module named YadaYadaYada'](//stackoverflow.com/q/10253826)

Comment: test is just for reference purpose. there are some different names related to our product. and `test` is not a package. It is the directory structure. test directory having test_framework and this having a pyfile test_a_feature having class

Comment: If `test` is not a package, **don't use it as a package**.

Comment: Instead, make sure the `test` directory is on your module search path, so add it to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, pytest does not include the current directory in `sys.path`. You can see that if you print the value inside any of your tests.

This is different than normal python session where `sys.path` contains the value `''`.

To make the import work inside pytest, you have to modify `sys.path` to include the module's location (but make sure you only make this change within specific tests to avoid side-effects.